# How to find closest of given numbers in java

Tags: java

Hi I am working on a java code to find closest of 3 numbers.

Input Format: 
Input consists of 4 integers. 
The first 3 integer values  correspond to P1, P2, P3,  the number of refugees who can be accommodated in the 3 camps C1, C2, C3 respectively at Khaldiya. 
The last input corresponds to the number of civilians from a locality.

Output Format: 
Print a single camp name  C1, C2 or C3 where those given number of civilians from a locality can be accomodated. 
Refer sample input and output for formatting specifications.

**Sample Input 1:**

```
650 
890 
345 
400
```

**Sample Output 1:**

```
C1
```

I wrote a code which does not pass all test cases. Can anyone help me where I am wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int p1,p2,p3,n;
    int diff = 0;
    p1=s.nextInt();
    p2=s.nextInt();
    p3=s.nextInt();
    n=s.nextInt();
    if((n<p1)||(n>p2)&&(n>p3))
        System.out.println("C1");
    else if((n<p2)||(n>p1)&&(n>p3))
        System.out.println("C2");
    else if((n<p3)||(n>p2)&&(n>p1)) 
        System.out.println("C3");
    }

}
```

Comment: Which test cases are wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that it only compares the values of the numbers. What if p1, p2 and p3 are all greater than n, but p3 is the closest? Your code still outputs C1, when it should output C3.

I think you should compare the difference between each p value and n.

```
int p1Diff = p1 - n;
int p2Diff = p2 - n;
int p3Diff = p3 - n;
```

And then you set the negative differences to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

```
if (p1Diff < 0) {
    p1Diff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
// ...
```

And then you can find the smallest of the above three variables:

```
if (p1Diff < p2Diff && p1Diff < p3Diff) {
    System.out.println("C1");
}
if (p2Diff < p1Diff && p2Diff < p3Diff) {
    System.out.println("C2");
}
if (p3Diff < p1Diff && p3Diff < p2Diff) {
    System.out.println("C3");
}
```

Comment: It is showing c3 instead of c1 for 650 
890 
345 
400

Comment: @UtkarshaTiwari oops! Forgot to check if the camps have enough space. See the edit.

Comment: @UtkarshaTiwari I realised that I was wrong again, see the second edit.

Comment: Do we really require difference?

Comment: Then how are you going to determine which is the closest? @UtkarshaTiwari